# How to transform the "multi_hand_landmarks" to "numpy array"?

Tags: python, dataframe, mediapipe

I've been working on a program for hand pose recognition with Python.And there is an class named "multi_hand_landmarks" , which contains 21 3D hand-knuckle coordinates.Each coordinates is showed like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjWpZ.png)
Now I'm going to calculate the coordinates of the midpoint between two joints,but I've failed to transform these data to any other type,here is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved.I used to consider the "landmark" as List,but actually not.
If you want to get the x-coordinate of a joint,you should code like this:

```
    hand_feature= hander.process(img)
    for landmark in hand_feature.multi_hand_landmarks:  
        x=landmark.landmark[0].x  # You can replace the "0" with any number you want
        print(x)
```

It's extremely a pain in the ass that we should code "**landmark.landmark**[0].x" rather than "**landmark**[0].x" !